# Tokenizing in Java like Python's re.Scanner

Tags: java

Python has `re.Scanner` that can be used to tokenize strings easily. Here is a quick example:

```
class TokenType(Enum):
    integer = 1
    float = 2

scanner = re.Scanner([
    (r"\d+\.\d*", lambda s, t:(TokenType.float, float(t))),
    (r"\d+", lambda s, t:(TokenType.integer, int(t))),
    (r".", lambda s, t: None)
])

input = "1024 3.14"

tokens = scanner.scan

pprint(tokens)
```

Output:

```
[(<TokenType.integer: 1>, 1024),
 (<TokenType.float: 2>, 3.14)]
```

Does Java's standard library have equivalent functionality?

Comment: Yes, and it is called... [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html). Seems like 5 seconds of searching should find that, but, sometimes the javadoc can be a tad hard to find I guess, so here you go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really.

Java has the [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html), which reads tokens from a `String`, `InputSteam` etc, but it doesn't support a conditional consumer like the one you've shown.

`Scanner` has methods such as `hasNextFloat()` and `hasNextInt()` to detect what's coming next, but these would not be useful because both would return `true` for both of your example numbers.

You would have to read the next "word" as a `String` (using `getNext()`), then process and parse it as a float/int depending on it having a dot or not.